# React Router- Different navigation component styles on different pages

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-router

I'm getting started with react and at the moment I'm struggling to adjust the styling of my navigation through different pages of my app. Despite the thorough research I made on this, I struggled to find a concise and simple explanation on how to make this possible.

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import '../src/styles/main.css';
import Navigation from './components/layout/Navigation';
import Footer from './components/layout/Footer';
import Home from './components/pages/Home';
import About from './components/pages/About';
import Contact from './components/pages/Contact';

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="App">
        <Navigation />
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
          <Route path="/about" component={About} />
          <Route path="/contact" component={Contact} />
          <Footer />
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Navigation.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import logo from '../../images/logo.png'

function  Navigation () {

  return (
    <header>
      <Link to="/"><a href="" className="menu__brand"><img className="logo" src={logo} alt=""/></a>  </Link>
      <nav className="menu">
        {/* <img src="./images/menu.svg" alt="Menu bar" className="hero__menu-icon"/> */}
        <ul className="menu__items">
          <li className="menu__item">  <a href="">Portfolio</a>  </li>
          <li className="menu__item"> <Link to="/about"> <a href="">About</a> </Link> </li>
          <li className="menu__item"> <Link to="/contact"> <a href="">Contact</a></Link></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
    
  )
}

export default Navigation;
```

I've been battling with this for a while now and didn't get any success due to my limited knowledge in React. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you saying you want to style navigation differently on each page?

Comment: Yes. For instance, on my home page I would like my navigation to have a position of absolute. For all the other pages I would like to remove the position of absolute.